# Сажать или садить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если речь идет, например, об овощах, то что мы с ними делаем: сажаем или садим? Сразу вспоминается песня советский времен "Пионеры сажают леса". А что при этом делает полицейский с преступником: садит в тюрьму или сажает?
В чем разница между этими словами и какие из них правильное? А еще есть ли смысловая разница между понятиями "садить" и "сажать", и в каком случае какое слово употребляется?

Answer (score 4):

Овощи, преступников и все остальное сажаем. В словарях "садить" есть, но с пометкой простореч. или сниж. разг.

По значению "сажать" и "садить" близки. У Даля "сажать" более множественное, а "садить" более решительное.

Слово "садить" есть в русской народной песне: "Сама садик я садила, сама буду поливать. Сама милого любила, сама буду забывать..." Эту же песню использует в поэме "Во весь голос" В. Маяковский.

Answer (score 3):

Садить – это народно-просторечный вариант глагола «сажать»: С. хлебы в печь. С. огурцы, капусту.

Другим значение слова «садить» является «с силой, с особым усердием делать что-либо»: С. кулаком в грудь. С. картечью, шрапнелью (стрелять, бить). С. мячом по воротам.

Также "сильно пахнуть" (о неприятном запахе). На кухне садит чесноком.

Answer (score -3):

Садим — деревенский разговорный сленг. Проверочный вопрос: что делаем? — Сажаем. Что делаю? — Сажаю.